# Add read more at end of paragraph

Tags: css

I want to add read more in paragraph. I have tried adding read more button through JavaScript, but now I just want to know that can I add read more button at end of paragraph only through CSS?

Comment: See if this article answers your question. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/ — You might want to experiment with toggling the `.truncate` class to hide/reveal text.

Comment: it is impossible to notify on none-element, even if you show **read more** at the end of para. What you really need is to notify click **read more** button, isn't it? So you should add html element for **read more** which means there is no way with only css

Answer (score 1):

This might help, just add display: inline; to child elements. So that they are not in a separate block.

```css
.parent > * {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
    Placeat dolores atque id veritatis nihil officiis deserunt quas quibusdam possimus. 
  </p>
  <button>show less</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, just add display: inline; to child elements. So that they are not in a separate block.

```html
<div class="parent">
      <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
        Placeat dolores atque id veritatis nihil officiis deserunt quas quibusdam possimus. 
      </p>
      <button>show less</button> 
    </div>
```

```css
.parent > * {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
        Placeat dolores atque id veritatis nihil officiis deserunt quas quibusdam possimus. 
      </p>
      <button>show less</button> 
</div>
```